# How to impose that both real variables can't be simultaneously strictly positive linearly?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling

I have two variables: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that are reals (NOT binary) and I want to express the fact that they can't be strictly positive at the same time (i.e.  $\alpha=0$ or $\beta=0$) with a linear constraint but I don't manage to do it.

Comment: Sorry, that is non-convex. In general, this cannot be done in a pure LP. It can be formulated as a (non-convex) NLP or a MIP.

Answer (score 1):

You want a linear function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\alpha, \beta) > 0$ or $\ge 0$ (i.e. a linear constraint) if and only if $(\alpha, \beta)$ is in the complement of the open first quadrant; call that set $Q$.

This is impossible for $>$ because the constraint defines an open set in that case, and $Q$ is closed. So take $f(\alpha, \beta) \ge 0$. (We could consider $\le$, but by symmetry it's the same; just switch $f$ with $-f$.)

Now you still have a problem because $f^{-1}[0,\infty)$ for $f$ linear consists either of the empty set (if $f < 0$ is constant), the portion of the plane on one side of the line $f^{-1}(0)$ (if $f$ is non-constant), or the full plane (if $f \ge 0$ is constant).

So it can't be done.

Comment: Maybe I did not express clearly. I want sth like  $\alpha \cdot \beta = 0$ but expressed in a linear way. For binary variables, it would be easy but here, the 2 variables are real. So I expect more a "practical" explanation rather than a theoretical one...

Comment: What do you mean by "expressed in a linear way," then?

Comment: I've answered the question as posed. You'll have to clarify what qualifies as a linear constraint if you want a different answer.